# Swapping Textures in Metal with the Blit Command Encoder

Tags: shader, textures, metal

I recently implemented a water simulation in Metal using a ping pong buffer and compute shaders.  It is working well but I was just wondering what the cost of swapping the textures several times a frame would be and whether this could be improved by using the Blit Command Encoder?

Here is a sample of the code:

```
    let computeEncoder = commandBuffer.makeComputeCommandEncoder()!
    computeEncoder.setComputePipelineState(pipelineState)
    computeEncoder.setTexture(textureA, index: 0)
    computeEncoder.setTexture(textureB, index: 1)

    var width = pipelineState.threadExecutionWidth
    var height = pipelineState.maxTotalThreadsPerThreadgroup / width
    let threadsPerThreadGroup = MTLSizeMake(width, height, 1)
    width = Int(textureA.width)
    height = Int(textureA.height)
    let threadsPerGrid = MTLSizeMake(width, height, 1)

    computeEncoder.dispatchThreads(threadsPerGrid, threadsPerThreadgroup: threadsPerThreadGroup)
    computeEncoder.endEncoding()

    swap(&textureA, &textureB)
```

Comment: What does `swap` do in this case? If you are performing classical ping-pong buffering (render from A to B to A to B, and so on), then blitting is probably not what you are looking for since this would just copy the contents of one texture into another (instead of performing your compute shader).

Comment: In this case `swap` lets me read from the texture I have just written to in the previous compute pass.

Answer (score 0):

This method works nicely:

```
    let blitEncoder = commandBuffer.makeBlitCommandEncoder()

    blitEncoder?.copy(from: textureA, to: temp)
    blitEncoder?.copy(from: textureB, to: textureA)
    blitEncoder?.copy(from: temp, to: textureB)

    blitEncoder?.endEncoding()
```

I haven't done any tests to see if this improves performance although I assume it does.  Will post results once I have!

Comment: But why would you need to swap the contents when you could just swap the references/pointers in the next rendering pass? `computeEncoder.setTexture(textureB, index: 0); computeEncoder.setTexture(textureA, index: 1)`

Comment: Oh yes, that's a much better idea!  I forgot about that.